# Understanding a figure showing the wedge product

Tags: exterior-algebra, visualization

On the wikipedia article explaining [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#/media/File:N_vector_positive.svg) figure is shown, visualizing the relationship between the wedge product of 2 vectors (or differential forms for that matter), and the "orientation" of the resulting 2-Form or 3-Form on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In the 3-Form case, the orientation of the facets are shown with the circles. 1 Observation is, that faces with the same orientation as the vectors indicate, face the camera, where the others are in the opposite orientation. Why is that?

Also, why would these faces be oriented in this particular way? In what way is the 3-forms orientation related to the 2-forms making up it's faces?

Comment: It's really just not a good way of thinking about the orientation of a $k$-form. A 3-form **is not** "made up of 2-forms" in the sense the image suggests. What they're doing in these images is (1) choosing an arbitrary $k$-manifold with boundary which is "compatible" with the $k$-form in question; (2) choosing one of the two orientations ("inward" or "outward") that the $(k-1)$-manifold boundary has by virtue of being a boundary; and (3) declaring this to be the orientation of the $k$-form. The "circles" they show only work in 3D and are just a proxy for normal vectors.